# how can i insert 6 times value into mysql table in single query

Tags: php, html, mysql

I had table named as `subject`.I had columns `id`(PK), `subject_name`, `total_class`, `attendence`, and `cnic`(FK). My user fills the form and submitted it. I got values via post method of form. In form I had 6 subjects and for every subject I have `total_class`, `attendence`, `subject_name`.
Here is my code

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{

    $form=$_POST[form'];
    $s1=$_POST['sub1'];
    $s1=$_POST['sub2'];
    $s1=$_POST['sub3'];
    $s1=$_POST['sub4'];
    $s1=$_POST['sub5'];
    $s1=$_POST['sub6'];
    $month=$_POST['month'];

    $total_attend_1=$_POST['Ts1'];
    $total_attend_2=$_POST['Ts2'];
    $total_attend_3=$_POST['Ts3'];
    $total_attend_4=$_POST['Ts4'];
    $total_attend_5=$_POST['Ts5'];
    $total_attend_6=$_POST['Ts6'];

    $attend_1=$_POST['Attend_s1'];
    $attend_2=$_POST['Attend_s2'];
    $attend_3=$_POST['Attend_s3'];
    $attend_4=$_POST['Attend_s4'];
    $attend_5=$_POST['Attend_s5'];
    $attend_6=$_POST['Attend_s6'];
    $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO subject VALUE( '','$s1','total_attend_1','$attend_1','$form','$month')") or die(mysql_error());
    /*My query should be here.Should I write 6 insert queries?*/
```

I had tried it by using

```
foreach($array as $attendee){
}
```

but didn't got my task?
Can someone please help me?

Comment: First you need to learn about [arrays](http://php.net/array), then you need to learn about [sql injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com), then you need to learn about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: If you have a variable name with a number in it, *you should be using an array*

Comment: @sam: nothing wrong with variables with numbers in them. but variables with sequential/repeating numbers in them, definitely.

Comment: @MarcB - I rarely see identifiers with numbers used intelligently.

Answer (score 3):

The correct [insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) syntax is

```
insert into subject values (sub1, ts1, attend_s1);
```

or with multiple values

```
insert into subject values (sub1, ts1, attend_s1), (sub2, ts2, attend_s2), (...);
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want something like this:

```
function x($str) {return mysql_real_escape_string($str);} // shorter function name
$rows = Array();
for( $i=1; $i<=6; $i++) {
  $rows[] = "(null,'".x($_POST['sub'.$i])."','".x($_POST['Ts'.$i])."','".x($_POST['Attend_s'.$i])."','".x($form)."','".x($_POST['month'])."')";
}
mysql_query("insert into `subject` values ".implode(",",$rows));
```

Remove all the variable assignments, and make sure you define `$form` somewhere - I don't see it in the code you posted.

Comment: I think that answer from Olaf Dietsche is more human-readable and easier to understand for newbie.

Answer (score 1):

```
// $post = a sanitized copy of $_POST

$entries = array( );
for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; ++$i) {
    $entries[] = " (NULL, '{$post['sub'.$i]}', '{$post['Ts'.$i]}', '{$post['Attend_s'.$i]}', '{$form}', '{$post['month']}') ";
}

$query = " INSERT INTO `subject` VALUES ".implode(', ', $entries);
```